# Shading won't show up in the Properties shelf?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, interface

I'm trying to change shading from *MultiTexture* to *GLSL*, but I can't quite seem to find the option nor the panel where it should be. It's weird. No one else is having this problem.

[image]

Comment: Blender version?

Comment: Also the Multitexture/GLSL option doesn't work for Cycles

Comment: Still that Shading scroll should be present.. at least there are Backface Culling,  Matcaps setup. It's interesting situation, could you include screenshot of the whole Blender window when there isn't Shading present and if possible [blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

You have an old version of blender, either 2.66, 2.67 or 2.68. The current version is 2.78 with 2.79 to be released shortly.

In 2.69 the shading panel was added, before that the GLSL/Multitextured option was available in the Display panel and it is only available when Blender Render is the active render engine.